# File name replacing issue in Red5 stream record

Tags: actionscript-3, red5

I have created one as3 application to capture and save the mic or web cam in red5 server by streaming.
I am also changing the file name by passing argument in publish() function.

How I can check whether the any other file with same name already exists in the server or not.
I want to maintain the file name sequence in the server... 
Example: if the file name "xyz.flv" I sent through publish() and the xyz.flv already there in the server, then it should take the sequence of the file name like "xyz-1.flv" or "xyz-2.flv"...like that.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use a timestamp for the naming?
do something like:

```
var date_str:String = (today_date.getDate()+"_"+(today_date.getMonth()+1)+"_"+today_date.getFullYear()+"_"+today_date.getTime());               
newRecording = new Recording();             //create a record instance
newRecording.filename = "rec_" + date_str;  //name the file according to timestamp
```